# Unable To Upload Files and Folders To Apache Document Root After Changing Keypair On AWS Linux 2 Ec2 Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I tried adding ec2-user to Apache group over again and changing group ownership and write permissions with

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www && find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

But I'm still unable to upload files and folders. Connected to server as ec2-user using FileZilla.

What I'm I missing?

**UPDATE**

I Installed a new version of FileZilla. I'm now able to upload files / folders